# Windows 7 / Suddenly all Applications require 'Run as Administrator'

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac

I've been using Windows 7 for many years.  I just purchased a new machine about a week ago.  I installed all my traditional applications (MS Office, VS2015, SolidWorks, Matlab, ...).  Friday everything was going just fine after a week of use.

However, *yesterday* VS2015 and SolidWorks suddenly required *'Run as Administrator'* to function properly.  Seems suspicious.

- Why would this change 'overnight'?
- Does it imply an *inconvenient* Windows update?
- People 'say' that 'good software' should *never* require 'Run as Administrator'.  Did Microsoft mess up their own VS2015?  Is SolidWorks not 'good software'?
- Does it imply something more *insidious* like a virus?

Comment: Seems like my AppData directory ownership changed.  How could this happen without my explicit actions?

Answer (score 1):

Does it imply something more insidious like a virus, no virus comes with a purpose.

Try this
Right-click on the program's shortcut (or exe file) and choose Properties.

Switch to the compatibility tab and uncheck the box next to "Run this program as an administrator". Click "ok".

---

Source:

[How to remove Run as Administrator? - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/how-to-remove-run-as-administrator/e839a6ea-02c4-4ea4-99c2-7b00284d88af?auth=1)

Comment: I understand the work-around.  I don't understand what changed in my O/S.  On Friday, I didn't need to 'Run as Administrator'.  What changed in my system requiring me to run all applications as administrator?

Comment: Do I really need to change this on *every* single application?  Seems like a kludge...

Comment: I don`t think so, look at the user setting in the control panel. Maybe you logged in with another user

Comment: No.  I own my laptop.  There is only one user.  UAC settings were not changed by me.